# Quelle serait une meilleure façon d’exprimer: « J’aime être dans une position qui assure un support à ma tête »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation

Contexte:

Ma conjointe me demande pourquoi je ne viens pas m’installer auprès d’elle dans le fauteuil. Je lui réponds que j’aime être dans une position qui assure un support à ma tête ou à mes coudes. (Ici je fais allusion aux accoudoirs).

Merci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je ne vois pas de meilleure façon ou de façon idéale ; on peut exprimer plus ou moins d'idées et selon le moment être inspiré par une énonciation plus concise ou au contraire plus explicative.

- Je ne me sens bien en position assise qu'avec ma tête bien calée par des rembourrures.
- Il faut que ma tête épouse un appui-tête approprié quand je suis dans un fauteuil, autrement je suis mal à l'aise.
- Les fauteuils sans un bon appui-tête ajustable ne me conviennent pas, je ne peux pas me décontracter.
- Je trouve très peu confortables les fauteuils qui n'ont pas de quoi soutenir la tête.
- Dans un fauteuil il me faut un soutient pour la tête sinon je ne peux pas m'y maintenir  trop longtemps, je fatigue.
- J’aime être dans une position qui ménage un support à ma tête, sinon elle commence aussitôt à me peser.

En cherchant encore je pourrais certainement ajouter d'autres possibilités mais je m'arrête après cette sixième variante, bien qu'il soit toujours intéressant de remarquer les nouvelles nuances dont le langage est capable dans chaque possibilité venant grossir la liste. Qui donnera un moment de réflexion à cette question ne manquera probablement pas d'ajouter des formulations suggestives.

Answer (score 3):

Comme dit dans d'autres réponses il existe plein de possibilités. Je dirais :

> Merci mais je préfère quand ma tête est soutenue

> Merci mais je préfère avoir un appuie-tête

Le verbe "soutenir" est régulièrement employé pour parler de parties du corps : soutien-gorge, soutien lombaire,...

Answer (score 1):

Je trouve la formulation présentée excellente et je ne vois pas vraiment comment faire mieux. Je propose ce qui me vient spontanément ; c'est plus court mais pas necessairement *meilleur* :

> *Je préfère avoir un support pour ma tête.* [l'interlocuteur peut aisément déduire le choix du meuble qui procure la position recherchée etc.]
>  *Je préfère m'appuyer la tête/avoir la tête appuyée.* [j'emploierais le verbe [*accoter*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/accoter) au Canada/Québec.]